# How to synchronize the ground with the rotation of the wheel?

Tags: javascript, geometry, distance, angle

I want to sync the ground with the rotation of a wheel (pull the ground under with the wheel rotation). The wheel has a dynamic diameter.

In my example bellow the ground should keep moving to the left if I press the right arrow, but it doesn't.

```js
const wheel=$('#wheel')
const plane=$('#plane')
let degree=0
let interval
$(document).on('mousedown','span',event=>{
  let planeX=plane.offset().left
  interval=setInterval(()=>{
    if(event.currentTarget.id==='left')degree-=1 
    else degree+=1
    wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)')
    const radians=degree * (Math.PI / 180)
    const cos = Math.cos(radians)
    planeX+=cos
    plane.css('left',planeX+'px')
  },10)
})
$(document).on('mouseup','span',event=>clearInterval(interval))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:fixed;top:0; font-size:200%;"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="left">&lt;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="cursor:pointer;" id="right">&gt;</span></div>
  <div id="wheelContainer" style="position:fixed;bottom:1em;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);"><div id="wheel" style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid;border-radius:50%;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')"></div></div>
  <div id="plane" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:-1000vw;right:-1000vw;height:1em;border:1px solid;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total arc length is equal to the total angle (measured in radians) times the radius. Since the ground is *under* the wheel, you'll want opposite sign. So instead of

```
planeX+=cos
```

bettwer write

```
planeX = planeX0 - radians * radius
```

where radius would be 75px in your scenario.

```js
const wheel=$('#wheel')
const plane=$('#plane')
const radius=75
const planeX0=plane.offset().left
let degree=0
let interval
$(document).on('mousedown','span',event=>{
  interval=setInterval(()=>{
    if(event.currentTarget.id==='left')degree-=1 
    else degree+=1
    wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)')
    const radians=degree * (Math.PI / 180)
    planeX = planeX0 - radians * radius
    plane.css('left',planeX+'px')
  },10)
})
$(document).on('mouseup','span',event=>clearInterval(interval))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:fixed;top:0; font-size:200%;"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="left">&lt;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="cursor:pointer;" id="right">&gt;</span></div>
  <div id="wheelContainer" style="position:fixed;bottom:1em;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);"><div id="wheel" style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid;border-radius:50%;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')"></div></div>
  <div id="plane" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:-1000vw;right:-1000vw;height:1em;border:1px solid;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')"></div>
```

Comment: I also need to rotate the wheel with the mouse and I got stuck again. If you have the time my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469679/translate-a-plane-by-rotating-a-circle-with-the-mouse

Answer (score 0):

if you hold the arrow long enough, you will see the ground moves in sine function, whatever holding left or right arrow.

the problem is in this code:

```
const radians=degree * (Math.PI / 180)
const cos = Math.cos(radians)
planeX+=cos
```

the `degree` is an accumulative value, where `planeX +=` need a step change of value only.

**Solution:
If the degree is going to +=1 rad, the planeX should only +=1, or += 1 * radius of circle.**