# Translate a plane by rotating a circle with the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, angle

I have two button(the arrows), when they are pressed everything works as expected.

What is not working is moving the ground with the mouse(hover the mouse over the wheel to see), it keeps jumping back to previous value(shown by the numbers on the plane).

How to translate a plane by rotating a circle with the mouse?

```js
const plane = $('#plane')
const planeX = plane.offset().left
const wheel = $('.wheel>div')
const radius = wheel.width() / 2
let degrees = 0

// buttons
let interval
$(document).on('mousedown', 'span', event => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', 'rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.25)')
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (event.currentTarget.id === 'left') degrees -= 2
    else degrees += 2
    wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)').data('degree', degrees)
    plane.css('left', planeX - degrees * (Math.PI / 180) * radius + 'px')
  }, 10)
})
$(document).on('mouseup', 'span', () => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', '')
  clearInterval(interval)
})

// mouse
const offset = wheel.parent().offset()
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.interactive', event => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', 'rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.25)')
  const degreeOffset =
    Math.atan2(
      event.pageX - (offset.left + radius),
      event.pageY - (offset.top + radius)
    ) *
      (180 / Math.PI) *
      -1 -
    degrees
  $(document).on('mousemove', event2 => {
    const radians = Math.atan2(
      event2.pageX - (offset.left + radius),
      event2.pageY - (offset.top + radius)
    )
    degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1 - degreeOffset
    wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)').data('degree', degrees)
    plane.css('left', planeX - degrees * (Math.PI / 180) * radius + 'px')
  })
})
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.interactive', () => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', '')
  $(document).off('mousemove')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:fixed;top:0; font-size:200%;"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="left">&lt;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
      style="cursor:pointer;" id="right">&gt;</span></div>
  <div class="wheel" style="position:fixed;bottom:1em;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);">
    <div style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid;border-radius:50%;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')">
      <div class="interactive" style="border-radius:50%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0"></div>
      <div style="border:1px solid;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);background:white;width:25%;height:25%;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">X</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="plane" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:-100vw;width:300vw;height:1em;border:1px solid;display:flex;justify-content:space-around;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')"><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b><b>4</b><b>5</b><b>6</b><b>7</b><b>8</b><b>9</b></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler for mousemove did not account for moving over the 0 degree mark. I've updated the code to calculate the change in mouse position (e.g. `newMousePos - mousePos`) and account for moving across 0 degrees.

```js
const plane = $('#plane')
const planeX = plane.offset().left
const wheel = $('.wheel>div')
const radius = wheel.width() / 2
let degrees = 0

// buttons
let interval
$(document).on('mousedown', 'span', event => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', 'rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.25)')
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (event.currentTarget.id === 'left') degrees -= 2
    else degrees += 2
    wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)').data('degree', degrees)
    plane.css('left', planeX - degrees * (Math.PI / 180) * radius + 'px')
  }, 10)
})
$(document).on('mouseup', 'span', () => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', '')
  clearInterval(interval)
})

// mouse
const offset = wheel.parent().offset()
let mousePos = 0
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.interactive', event => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', 'rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.25)')
  const degreeOffset =
  Math.atan2(
    event.pageX - (offset.left + radius),
    event.pageY - (offset.top + radius)
  ) *
    (180 / Math.PI) *
    -1 -
    degrees
  $(document).on('mousemove', event2 => {
    const radians = Math.atan2(
      event2.pageX - (offset.left + radius),
      event2.pageY - (offset.top + radius)
    )

    const newMousePos = radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1 - degreeOffset
    let change = newMousePos - mousePos

    // adjust for moving over 0 deg.
    if (change < -180) change += 360
    else if (change > 180) change -= 360
    mousePos = newMousePos
    degrees += change

    wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)').data('degree', degrees)
    plane.css('left', planeX - degrees * (Math.PI / 180) * radius + 'px')
  })
})

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.interactive', () => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', '')
  $(document).off('mousemove')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:fixed;top:0; font-size:200%;"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="left">&lt;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
      style="cursor:pointer;" id="right">&gt;</span></div>
  <div class="wheel" style="position:fixed;bottom:1em;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);">
    <div style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid;border-radius:50%;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')">
      <div class="interactive" style="border-radius:50%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0"></div>
      <div style="border:1px solid;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);background:white;width:25%;height:25%;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">X</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="plane" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:-100vw;width:300vw;height:1em;border:1px solid;display:flex;justify-content:space-around;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')"><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b><b>4</b><b>5</b><b>6</b><b>7</b><b>8</b><b>9</b></div>
```